# Block editor not displaying properly

Tags: block-editor

So the block editor is not displaying properly. Just plain text, no styling, and no actual editor when I go into the page/post editor (this also applies to custom post types). I am running the latest version of Wordpress, 5.4. This happened briefly on the test server, but went away on its own so I pushed to the live site. It's back again and I don't know why or how to fix it. I CAN, however, workaround it by using the Classic Editor plugin. But even this is causing another problem, as some users are seeing the Classic Editor, and some are seeing the glitched out Blocks editor (this probably deserves a separate question in its own right, as we've exhausted the usual "clear the cache and reload the site" approaches).

[image: The broken Blocks editor]

The biggest hiccups I can think of came during the restoration process. The site I'm working on was transferred between hosts recently, and I used All-in-One WP migration to backup and transfer the site. While this plugin worked in the past, it appears a recent update broke it, and so I had to use an older version (version 6.77, verses the current version, 7.20) to restore the site. Is there any reason to believe that this older version can't handle newer versions of WordPress? I also had to edit these values in the php.ini file, while trying to restore the backup:

- upload_max_filesize = 256M
- post_max_size = 256M
- max_execution_time = 900
- memory_limit = 90

Here's a list of the plugins currently running on the site for reference:

[image: A list of plugins on the site]

Comment: It's quite possible that the older version of All-in-One WP Migration did break the site during migration as newer versions of Wordpress may have added things to the db that older versions of All-In-One aren't looking for.  Pure conjecture on my part but it is possible.  What's the PHP version on your new site?  Also, can you enable debug in the WP Config file and see what errors or notices are being thrown?

Comment: Pardon the delayed response, but PHP version is 7.2.24
Further, I have the debug and log enabled in wordpress-config, but there's no error log in wp-content, and I haven't overwritten the default debug log location. That said, it appears to be working now with no intervention besides forcing WordPress to reinstall the most recent update. However, I'm not sure if it's truly solved yet or if its going to flop back and forth from working and not working.

Comment: Could be that the WordPress update failed for some reason and you had a corrupted WP install.  I have seen it happen but only like twice.  Both times was on a shared hosting platform.

Comment: Well, it is shared hosting, so it sounds right. How did you address the problem? Let it be, or was some intervention required beyond forcing the re-install?

Comment: I manually copied over the code WP files and then went and downloaded all the plugins and re-uploaded them 1 by 1.  What I found key, via FTP was a) do directories 1 at a time, b) don’t try to access the site.

Comment: So I did another restore of the backup on a clean WP install, and the problem didn't carry over, so that hackish restoration with the old plugin appeared to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with Tony Djukic, I attempted to restore my backup with a different plugin, Duplicator. This particular plugin creates its own fresh install of WP. Having run that script, everything in the site is working fine as of me writing this. It appears that using the old version of All-in-One WP Migration caused some sort of problem, but I can only speculate what exactly. It seems to have failed to properly update the DB, but I am not sure. Regardless, I found a solution that works, even if I don't know why, so for now I'm happy.